# How do I search one list of words in another showing matches?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

Good morning,

I need to get the following:

I want to search for the following groups:

Grupo 1
Grupo 2

Of the following users:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUIsb.png)

And that gives me the following result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPD70.png)

Would it be possible to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Using your provided example, (assuming you are on Excel 2019, 2021, or 365) in cell D2 and copied down:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" y ",TRUE,REPT({"Grupo 1","Grupo 2"},COUNTIF(C2,"*"&{"Grupo 1","Grupo 2"}&"*")))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an array solution under O365. It spills the entire result. On cell `D1` put the following formula:

```
=LET(B, B2:B3, BYROW(B, LAMBDA(bb, LET(s, TEXTSPLIT(bb,", "),
 TEXTJOIN(" y ",,XLOOKUP({"Grupo 1","Grupo 2"}, s, s,""))))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]